# from iostat -En output ,i need to display Hard Error more than 2

Tags: bash, solaris

I need to display the lines which are having Hard Errors more than 2 from the output of `iostat -En | grep Hard` in case of solaris.

Answer (score 0):

This will show lines with more than two hard errors:

```
iostat -En | nawk '/Hard Errors/ {line=$0;gsub(/.*Hard Errors:/,"");if($1>2) printf("%s\n",line); }'
```

Comment: ya surely ,thank you this answer helped me a lot.